# Using an object as a key is causing problems

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, dictionary, object

I'm currently experiencing an issue when trying to use an object as a key.
I wanted to use the user at index 0 as key for the game as index 0, but when I do this all game objects are updated with the new user item. Here is the code i'm using:

```
class User():
    def __init__(self, user_id, age, name):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.age = age
        self.name = name


class Game():
    score = {}
    def __init__(self, difficulty):
        self.difficulty = difficulty
        
        
# users
users_list = [User(1, 'Jake', 19), User(2, 'George', 32), User(3, 'Harry', 27)]

# games
game_list = [Game('Easy'), Game('Intermediate'), Game('Hard')]


# Give user in index 0 score of 1000 for easy game
game_list[0].score[users_list[0]] = 1000

print(game_list[0].score)
print(game_list[1].score)
print(game_list[2].score)
```

Here is the output after running the above code:

```
{<__main__.User object at 0x7fc9b6cdd4c0>: 1000}
{<__main__.User object at 0x7fc9b6cdd4c0>: 1000}
{<__main__.User object at 0x7fc9b6cdd4c0>: 1000}
```

I should have probably made a separate score class I suppose, but anyhow I would love to know what is the reason behind this. Any help and advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`score` is declared outside of the `__init__` method, so it is shared across *all* instances of `Game`.

Here's what you're looking for (make score instance-level):

```py
def __init__(self, difficulty):
    self.difficulty = difficulty
    self.score = {}
```

Comment: Ah! thanks for the quick and clear response